# What is the Google Drive file parents limit

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using Google Drive as a storage and decided to put one file into multiple folders (~500) in my case. I called Google Drive v2 API `PUT files` method to update file parents. It returns me error 400.

Does anybody know what is the `addParents` and `removeParents` limitation?

Comment: There seems to be no mention of its limitations. [Error 400: Bad Request](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#400_bad_request) is a Bad Request. Did you try indicating only one parameter to see if your passing a valid value?

Comment: @noogui problem is with `addParents` argument. If parents amount I want to add is ~500 (like in my case) Google Drive API responded with Error 400, that indicates client error. I had to split this request to few requests and add ~200 parents at a request. Then its works correct, so there is a limitation for `addParents` argument, but I can't find any words about that in docs.